# AngularJS ng-click event is not firing when inside nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, onclick, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have problem with ng-click (I'm using angular 1.0.4). First ng-click works but second no.

```
    <div class="menu-group" ng-repeat="module in modules">
         <div ng-click="toggle($event, $parent)" class="group-head">{{module.group.name}} <span class="{{module.group.icon}}"></span></div>
         <ul class="menu collapsed" ng-init="items = module.group.items">
              <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="openCategory($event, '{{item.name}}')">{{item.display}}</li>
         </ul>
    </div>
```

Generated code looks good:

```
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="openCategory($event, 'simpleName')" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Simple name</li>
```

Comment: @mikel without this mark is the same. However if I remove {{item.name}} and type something it works

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of `'{{item.name}}'` just use `item.name`

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/QNKZDT9N5k2tQaRrFlwY?p=preview